# Invisible main window

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, directx, invisible

I'm working on a DirectX GUI library, and the main class works by creating a main window, and then porting the input to all the GUI windows, which will handle the events. The problem is, the main window is a Win32 window (to handle messages), and needs to be invisible. Is there a way to create and invisible window and then be able to handle messages and draw things with DirectX?

Comment: Win32 windows are generally created invisible. the question is therefore difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3):

In the WM_CREATE of your WindowProc, do:

```
ShowWindow( hwnd, SW_HIDE );
```